# Clojure Type Hints for High Order Functions

Tags: clojure

I am creating a small application to learn Clojure and I just enabled the warnings on reflection feature for my code and I discovered a number of places where I could add type hints to enrich my code and improve performance.

However, I'm getting the warning from a few places in my code where I'm using high order functions or short anonymous syntax notation and I'm not sure how I could possibly fix those cases without expanding the function definitions.

For example, consider the following code:

```cli
(deftest test-java-expenses
    (testing "Testing Expenses"
        (let [total-cents (map (memfn amountInCents) expenses)]
            (is (= 7406 (apply + total-cents))))))
```

Where `expenses` is a vector containing objects of some type/class named `Expense`.

It seems that the complaint is about `amountInCents`, Clojure is using reflection on the arguments passed to determine their type (i.e. `Expense`).

I can fix the warning by changing `(memfn amountInCents)` for `(fn [^Expense e] (.amountInCents e))` but that just makes my code harder to read and in my opinion less elegant.

I would have the same problem if I had something like this: `#(.amountInCents %)` using the special syntax for anonymous function declarations.

I also considered using an annotated function to create the expense objects, one whose return type was tagged with its type, hoping the type would be inferred later, as follows

```cli
(defn new-expense ^Expense [date-string dollars cents category merchant-name]
    (Expense. date-string dollars cents category merchant-name))
```

And then create my expenses doing:

```cli
(def expenses [(new-expense "2009-8-24" 44 95 "books" "amazon.com")
               (new-expense "2009-8-25" 29 11 "gas" "shell")])
```

But that did not work either; the compiler still does not infer that the vector in question is a vector of `Expense` objects.

Is there a way to resolve the reflection warning for cases like those above where I use the `#()`, or the other case where I am passing a function as an argument to a high order function (e.g. `memfn`)?  I mean, a way without having to expand the function declaration myself (e.g. `(fn [^Type n] ....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just need to add a type hint to the `memfn` call?

From the [`memfn` docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn) (where `memfn` is described as `(memfn name & args)`):

> `name` may be type-hinted with the method receiver's
>   type in order to avoid reflective calls.

So in your case you can use:

```
(memfn ^Expense amountInCents)
```

to avoid the reflection.

Comment: That will teach me to RTFM. That was exactly what I was looking for.